# http get not working in cordova

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, cordova, http-get

Using visual studio 2017, cordova and running the index.js script:

```
    function onDeviceReady(){
    (...)
    document.getElementById("Button1").addEventListener("click", getfromAPI);
    function getfromAPI() {
        var theUrl = "https://haveibeenpwned.com/api/v2/breaches";
        var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
        var response = request.responseText;
        console.log(response);

        request.open("GET", theUrl, true);
        request.send(null);
    }
```

Unfortunately nothing is collected into the log, I'm not sure if the request is working at all?

I have tried different placing of some commands but it didn't make any difference:

```
    function onDeviceReady(){
    (...)
    document.getElementById("Button1").addEventListener("click", getfromAPI);
    function getfromAPI() {
        var theUrl = "https://haveibeenpwned.com/api/v2/breaches";
        var request = new XMLHttpRequest();


        request.open("GET", theUrl, true);
        request.send(null);
        var response = request.responseText;
        console.log(response);

    }
```

Content security policy looks like:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' data: 
gap: https://ssl.gstatic.com 'unsafe-eval'; 
style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; 
media-src *">
```

Comment: do you have whitelist plugin installed? do you have a Content-Securiy-Policy meta tag?

Comment: yes whitelist plugin seems to be installed according to the config.xml, I have also added the content security policy tag in the description

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 2 problems:

1. The CSP. You have to add haveibeenpwned to it to allow the connection `<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' data: gap: https://ssl.gstatic.com https://haveibeenpwned.com 'unsafe-eval'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *">`
2. The XHR code is not correct. You have to listen for the `onreadystatechange`

   ```
   request.onreadystatechange = function() {
       if (request.readyState == 4 && request.status == 200) {        
           console.log(request.responseText);        
       }
   };
   ```